# Runtimeexception when installing an extension via composer in typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I got an error when i try to install extension(Bw Focuspoint Images) via composer in typo3.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
[RuntimeException]

Please help.
[image]

Composer was already installed in my project. I want to install one extension to this project via composer. The steps i taken are,

1. login to my project by ssh
2. Then i give composer req blueways/bw-focuspoint-images
   After that i got the error which was in image

I am getting this error

```
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: blueways/bw-focuspoint-images:v3.0.2
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
[RuntimeException]                                                           
  /public/typo3conf/ext/bw_focuspoint_images does not exist and could not be created.  
Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php:186
 Composer\Util\Filesystem->ensureDirectoryExists() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:206
 Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->download() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:197
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->installCode() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:101
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->install() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:173
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->install() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:160
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:611
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:232
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:248
 Composer\Command\RequireCommand->doUpdate() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:205
 Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:283
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:113
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/bin/composer:64
 require() at /usr/bin/composer:24
```

```
require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Thank you. The extension got installed but it displaying another error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW22t.png)

Comment: You forgot to share the error message, and your attemps to resolve the problem

Comment: This is the error
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content. [RuntimeException]

Comment: Pretty strange. Unless you share more details (like the text that is hidden in your screenshot), it's impossible to tell you how to resolve the problem

Comment: sorry for that... i will update the image

Comment: To be clear: Please provide at least the full RuntimeException. And your used full composer command.  At best, try to add '-vv' or '-vvv' to your your command. I tested it on a v10 composer installation with `composer req blueways/bw-focuspoint-images:^3" and it installed it without issues. Please also check used php version to invoke composer and used composer version.

Comment: composer req blueways/bw-focuspoint-images

This is the command i given for installation

Comment: Please do not simply update the image - that's pure text content, so please share it as text. Also, share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Also, did you read that error message? What would happen if you check the permissions for that folder that should get created?

Comment: where can i add -vv?

Comment: Composer was already installed in my project. I want to install one extension to this project via composer. The steps i taken are,
1. login to my project by ssh
2. Then i give composer req blueways/bw-focuspoint-images
After that i got the error which was in image

Comment: So, did you read the error message? If not, please do so now, and share what you've tried to resolve the problem. Also, add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important information

Comment: I just tried these steps only. My typo3 version is 10.4.21. I tried these steps again after clear composer cache.

Comment: Execute on commandline `composer -v req blueways/bw-focuspoint-images`. -v is for verbose and it's listed here in global options: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options. Options for req / require are listed here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require-r

Comment: I have updated the error in my question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: `/public/typo3conf/ext/bw_focuspoint_images does not exist and could not be created.` - did you read that? What did you try to resolve that error?

Comment: I didn't know how to resolve that. I want to install bw_focuspoint_images extension.

Comment: Why not try to create that folder by hand, or check whether the permissions are set properly such that Composer could create the folder

Comment: How can i create that folder? or how can I set the permission for composer to create the folder. I am sorry, I am new to typo3.

Comment: How did you create any other folder on your system? `mkdir` could help. How did you configure permissions for the rest of Typo? `chmod` could help

Comment: I Give this command 
mkdir bw_focuspoint_images  
Then I got this
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘bw_focuspoint_images’: File exists

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a file or a directory?

Comment: its directory. I tried to create the directory

Comment: Thank you. The extension got installed but it displaying another error. Can you please help? i have added the screenshot in question edit.

Comment: As usual, share all details in text form. Also, if this is a new problem, please post a new question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. The solution for this issue is,

1. I created the directory for the extension through composer using
   mkdir bw_focuspoint_images
2. Then I give the command to install that plugin
   composer req blueways/bw-focuspoint-images

And it's successfully installed.

Comment: Weired - eventually the permissions are kind of screwed.